# Select a xHTML tag and store its properties into an array using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, xhtml

how can i use jquery todo:
1- read a specific URL
2- store a specific xhtml tag values into an array
3- pass this array to PHP script

these are the tags

```
<img class="nytmm_slidingMultimedia_imageSlide" style="display: inline; height: 620px; width: 930px;" src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2011/02/28/world/africa/20110301_LIBYA-slide-FBZQ/20110301_LIBYA-slide-FBZQ-jumbo.jpg">
```

in the above tag i want to store a list of src into an array ( there are may img tags with different src )

```
<div class="nytmm_bigPhotoGallery_caption">Residents of Sabratha rallied in support of Colonel Qaddafi in front of a bank where they were waiting to receive a one-time 300 Dinar bonus offered to every Libyan citizen by the regime.</div>
```

in the above tag i want to store the value or the text inside the div into another array
( there are may div tags with different content )

then i want to pass those 2 arrays to php where i can manage to do the rest of the tasks.

thanks and regards

Comment: I'm not the person who down-voted your question, but I think someone else did simply because you haven't told us what you've tried already. You're assumed to have made an effort on your own, before posting here...

Comment: i'm so sorry, the problem is that i tried for hours today to find a solution by searching on google by i didn't find it. i dont program using jquery, i program using PHP and i'm currently in the learning process of jquery so i wanted to know how to do such things using jquery. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var requestData = {}; // data object for future ajax request
requestData.src = []; // array for storing your src values
// getting multiple src values
$('.nytmm_slidingMultimedia_imageSlide').each(function(index){
  requestData.src.push($(this).attr('src'));
});
// getting single div text, be sure that there is only one div selected
requestData.text = $('.nytmm_bigPhotoGallery_caption').first().text();
// make an ajax request
$.post( 'some/handler.php', requestData, function(response) { console.log(response)} );
```

There is only some examples of how to get single value and multiply.

Comment: how to run this for the following url http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/world/africa/2011-feb-libya-slide-show.html, this url contains these classes

Comment: Ok, you just look at the source of the page, real source not the generated. Can you see those classes? You can run some code on the NY Times with Firebug, for learning I think :) You can get the code of the page with `$.get("http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/world/africa/2011-feb-libya-slide-show.html");` but this must be allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. As you can see every image data there is located in JS file [example](http://graphics8.nytimes.com/packages/js/multimedia/data/BigPhotoGalleryHTML/20110228-libya-gallery.js). You PHP programmer, right? So write your own PHP parser.